# passing custom class to component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am working on a progress bar component and i need to pass a custom class to it. I already have a -webkit-progress-value class as follows.

```
&::-webkit-progress-value {
        background-color: currentColor;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
      }
```

I have a `background: something` property that i need to put it in class and pass as custom prop class value to component but i am confused where to create that class since i already have one for value above.

My scss file looks like below:

```
:local {
  .progress-bar {
    background: #d3d4d5;
    ....more properties....

    &:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    &[value] {
       ....properties....

      &::-webkit-progress-bar {
       ....properties....
      }

      &::-webkit-progress-value {
        background-color: currentColor;
       ....properties....
      }

      &::-ms-fill {
       ....properties....
      }
    }

    &[value='100'],
    &[value='0'] {
      &::-webkit-progress-value {
        background: currentColor;
       ....properties....
      }

      &::-ms-fill {
       ....properties....
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to create one outside of local

```
.test{
  background: something;
}
```

and passed it to component `<component prop1={value} prop2={value} className={"test"} />` component is using that class but class properties are not getting applied so wondering if am not creating the class correctly.

what is it i am doing wrong?

Update: component code looks like this:

```
const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

const propTypes = { 

..props here...

}

const component = ({ ...props...}) => {
  const classes = cx([
    'progress-bar',
    heightSize,
    customProps.className,
  ]);

  return (
    <progress
      {...customProps}
      style={{ color: customProps.color }}
      className={classes}
      max={100}
      value={normalizedValue}
      aria-valuemax={100}
      aria-valuemin={0}
      aria-valuenow={normalizedValue}
      tabIndex="-1"
    />);
};
```

Also i am seeing the class properties being strikes out in developer tools.

Comment: Can you post the code for `component`?

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: Where's `classNames` coming from? I assume the "progress" component is a custom component, in which case it should be capitalized (Progress). Are you seeing errors in the DevTools console?

Comment: classNames are being imported import classNames from 'classNames/bind` . don't see any errors in console